# Decrypting SAML 2 Assertion

Tags: java, opensaml

I have the following SAML response that I need to decrypt and verify.

```
<saml:EncryptedAssertion xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
    <xenc:EncryptedData xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#" Id="ED-13b5261b-6429-4fc6-9df4-00ba4c956df4" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element">
        <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/>
        <ds:KeyInfo xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <xenc:EncryptedKey Id="EK-cde830f3-5741-440c-a6a3-03d7fc29bec7">
                <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                </xenc:EncryptionMethod>
                <ds:KeyInfo>
                    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference
                            xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
                        <ds:X509Data>
                            <ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                                <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=Foo,OU=Ba,O=Foobaa,C=AU
                                </ds:X509IssuerName>
                                <ds:X509SerialNumber>161...39233</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                            </ds:X509IssuerSerial>
                        </ds:X509Data>
                    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
                </ds:KeyInfo>
                <xenc:CipherData>
                    <xenc:CipherValue>
                        OrjesuK...lOQ==
                    </xenc:CipherValue>
                </xenc:CipherData>
            </xenc:EncryptedKey>
        </ds:KeyInfo>
        <xenc:CipherData>
            <xenc:CipherValue>
                RHkpDrgRX0AJprMr...k62Q==
            </xenc:CipherValue>
        </xenc:CipherData>
    </xenc:EncryptedData>
</saml:EncryptedAssertion>
```

I have access to the public and private keys used in encrypted and I am currently trying to decrypt it using the following code:

```
// Given here a EncryptedAssertion type populated from the above xml

// Open and initialise the Keystore
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("keystoreUrl")) {
    ks.load(fileInputStream, config.getBAMKeystorePassword().toCharArray());
}
PrivateKey certificate= (PrivateKey) ks.getKey("privateKeyAlias", null);

// Decrypt the encrypted assertion
BasicX509Credential cred = new BasicX509Credential();
cred.setPrivateKey(certificate);
StaticKeyInfoCredentialResolver resolver = new StaticKeyInfoCredentialResolver(cred);
Decrypter decrypter = new Decrypter(resolver, resolver, new InlineEncryptedKeyResolver());
decrypter.setRootInNewDocument(true);
Assertion decrypted = decrypter.decrypt(encryptedAssertion);
```

This however gives an exception of:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Data decryption key may not be null
```

I've tried several different combinations of loading the key, but cannot locate the error. Is someone able to please help me in progressing?

Comment: Have you checked if the certificate variable is null?

Comment: Yeah it loads a not-null value from file.

Comment: Try running debug to understand why it is null. Might be that you do not read the file from the right place. Might be something with the structure of the file?

Comment: I see you use "keystoreUrl" as file path. Is this the acctual path or have you replaced it in this example